# One image two time display in react, firebase storage

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I am currently learning firebase storage

I am trying display the image using firebase storage

but I am facing some problems with one image two time display

I check the code multiple time but I could not find the problem

**full code**

```
function Storege() {
const [addImage, setAddImage] = useState(null)
const[getImage, setGetImage] = useState([])


// add image in storage function
useEffect(()=>{
  if(addImage == null) return; 
    console.log('this is running')
  const imageRef = ref(projectStorage, `images/${addImage.name + v4()}`);
 uploadBytes(imageRef, addImage).then((snapshot)=>{
   alert('success is my hobit')
   getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref).then((url)=>{
     setGetImage((prev)=>[...prev, url])
   })
 })
}, [addImage,setAddImage])



const getImageRef = ref(projectStorage, 'images/')

// display image function
useEffect(()=>{
  listAll(getImageRef).then((response)=>{
    response.items.forEach((item)=>{
      getDownloadURL(item).then((url)=>{
        setGetImage((prev)=>[...prev, url])
      })
    })
  })
}, [])


  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input type="file" onChange={((event)=>{setAddImage(event.target.files[0])})}/>
      </div>

     {getImage && getImage.map((display)=>{
       return(
         <div>
           <img src={display} alt="photos" />
         </div>
       )
     })}
    </div>
  )

}

export default Storege
```

**Thanks**

Comment: What isn't working about the code you shared? Which specific line is causing that problem? Is there an error message?

Comment: Your list should have a unique key prop for each item e.g. `key={display}` (src or url would be a better name btw)